# Why can not I run Intellij on Linux Mint for Java version error?

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, linux-mint

When I try to run intellij, it shows the following message-

> Can not start under java 1.7.0_51-b13:Java 1.8 or later is required!

But when I checked the version of the Java in the machine-

```
java -version
```

I get-

```
java version "1.8.0_60" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
1.8.0_60-b27) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

What could be the reason for not working this?

Comment: You should configure IntelliJ to work with Java 8.

Comment: How so? I cant run this for the first time!

Comment: What are you running to execute the intillij command?

Comment: Im using ./idea.sh

Comment: Try setting the value of IDEA_JDK to point to the correct JDK, otherwise it seems it tries to auto detect it and it might be choosing an incorrect version.

Comment: One more thing, do you have the java 8 jdk installed? If it is just the JRE then intellij might be finding the only jdk you have.

Comment: you may want to check the following environment variables: IDEA_JDK, JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME. If you can read the script file, you can open and see how it set the JDK path.

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of IntelliJ IDEA [explicitly require Java 8 to run](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under).

Some things that can be done:

- Uninstall older versions of Java
- Ensure that `which java` points to the correct version of Java
- Ensure that Java 8 is selected via `update-alternatives --config java`
- Check the variables `IDEA_JDK`, `JDK_HOME`, and `JAVA_HOME`, and be sure they don't point to Java 7.  If all else fails, IDEA defaults to whichever `java` is on the path, so unsetting those variables may be a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have a `JAVA_HOME` env variable set ? If yes, it might use this version instead of the `java` binary available in your path.

Comment: I am not sure why people are downvoting this. The idea.sh goes through a couple different env variables to check for a jdk. `IDEA_JDK`, `IDE_HOME`, `JDK_HOME`, `JAVA_HOME` and finally it uses `which java`

Comment: And it seems to be the problem of the OP, because the java binary is correct (1.8) but IntelliJ uses an other version...